Need to add support for API Level 25
So I am working on an SDK , one of our users has an android app which runs in API Level 25. Now as soon as he adds our sdk as a dependency, the build fails with the following error
../../.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-25.4.0.aar/724f3e33e3a015bf03bd0343723b0f2d/res/values/values.xml

error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found. Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found., sources=[/Users/amanjn38/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-25.4.0.aar/724f3e33e3a015bf03bd0343723b0f2d/res/values/values.xml:214:5-69], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

error: resource android:attr/font not found. Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource android:attr/font not found., sources=[/Users/amanjn38/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-25.4.0.aar/724f3e33e3a015bf03bd0343723b0f2d/res/values/values.xml:214:5-69], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found. Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found., sources=[/Users/amanjn38/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-25.4.0.aar/724f3e33e3a015bf03bd0343723b0f2d/res/values/values.xml:214:5-69], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found. Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found., sources=[/Users/amanjn38/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-25.4.0.aar/724f3e33e3a015bf03bd0343723b0f2d/res/values/values.xml:214:5-69], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found. Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found., sources=[/Users/amanjn38/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-25.4.0.aar/724f3e33e3a015bf03bd0343723b0f2d/res/values/values.xml:214:5-69], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

This is the only dependency I have in my sdk
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
The user doesn't want to upgrade the API Level. And I stopped using appcompat because it is deprecated.
I am trying to figure out a way to support API Level 25.

if that app is still using appcompat but your library uses androidx then you library will not work with that app. The app will also need to update to andoirdx

@tyczj Is there any way I can override these fields in my android app or maybe use add support in the SDK itself ?

no there is not
